# Entity Framework | Error: InvalidCastException: The field of type System.Int32 must be a string, array or ICollection type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

## Issue

I'm receiving the following error when I *submit* (or post) a request to my Home Controller, for a method called NewsletterSignup. The error is prompted after my newsletter form is submitted and *prior* to when this method is called and the object, capturing form data, is created, creating a situation where it's difficult to troubleshoot, and identify where this exact issue is propagating.

> **Error**
>
> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> **InvalidCastException**: The field of type System.Int32 must be a string, array or ICollection type.
>   ... System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute.IsValid(object value)
>
> ... System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
>
> ... System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)

## Files

> **AppDbContext.cs**
>
> Application Database Context

```cs
namespace KingsEye.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)  { }

        public DbSet<Home>       Home       { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pages>      Pages      { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Newsletter> Newsletter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> **CollectionModel.cs**
>
> View Model used on index.cshtml and shared newsletter.cshtml view

```cs
namespace KingsEye.Models
{
    public class CollectionModel
    {
        public Home       Home       { get; set; }
        public Pages      Pages      { get; set; }
        public Newsletter Newsletter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> **Newsletter.cs**
>
> Newsletter View Model

```cs
namespace KingsEye.Models
{
    public class Newsletter
    {
        #region Newsletter
        [Display(Name = "Newsletter ID: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Newsletter ID Required!")]
        public int     Id     { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Name: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string   Fname  { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-Mail Address: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string   Email  { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone Number: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public int      Phone  { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Active: ")]
        [MaxLength(1)]
        public int      Active { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "GUID: ")]
        [MaxLength(37)]
        public string   GUID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Create { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Update { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

> **HomeController.cs**
>
> Home Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> NewsletterSignup(CollectionModel model)
{ 
    <= Error: is prompting prior to the body of this method being called, 
              and the parameter object being populated with post data!!!

    var newsletter = new Newsletter
    {
        Id     = 0,
        Fname  = model.Newsletter.Fname,
        Email  = model.Newsletter.Email,
        Phone  = model.Newsletter.Phone,
        Active = 0,
        GUID   = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Create = DateTime.Now,
        Update = DateTime.Now
    };

    ...
}
```

> **_Newsletter.cshtml**
>
> Shared view for the newsletter form

```
@model CollectionModel

<div id="newsletter">

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <header>
            <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
            <div class="text">Newsletter</div>
            <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </header>

        <main>Subscribe to our newsletter</main>

        <footer>
            <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="NewsletterSignup" method="post" id="newsletter-form" class="text-danger input-form">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Id" type="hidden" value="0" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Fname" id="email-signed" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Newsletter.Fname"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Email" type="hidden" value="place@holder.com" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Phone" id="email-signed" class="form-control" placeholder="(000) 000-0000" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Newsletter.Phone"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group input-submit">
                    <input id="newsletter-subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn material-button" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Active" type="hidden" value="0" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.GUID" type="hidden" value="0" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Create" type="hidden" value="0" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Newsletter.Update" type="hidden" value="0" />
                </div>

            </form>
        </footer>
    }
    else
    {
        <main>
            Please <a asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="Register">Sign-Up</a> to Subscribe for a Newsletter!
        </main>
    }
</div>
```

## Goal

Would like to identify *where* this error is propagating from so that the exception in question can be debugged accordingly. Any advice or direction would surely be appreciated.

- Thanks and cheers in advance.

Comment: why does your "Active" integer have a MaxLength attribute?

Comment: The "Active" integer is a boolean value, i.e., 0 (off) 1 (on)

Comment: Your phone number field can't be an integer. It has to be a string if you want to be able specify the data annotation you have on it. (phone numbers can have leading zeroes for example... And they technically aren't "numbers" anyways). Not related to your error but Your active column should probably be a boolean (if it's mapped to a sql Bit field)

Comment: integers can't have a MaxLength attribute, as integer columns typically have no scale/size arguments. Remove that data annotation and, if necessary, specify the column type instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MaxLenght attribute is for a string

```
    [Display(Name = "Active: ")]
    [MaxLength(1)] // this will fail
    public int      Active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "GUID: ")] 
    [MaxLength(37)] //this is okay
    public string   GUID { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.8

> Gets the maximum allowable length of the array or string data.

Answer (score -2):

Maxlengh property is causing trouble in your code.You may dont face any issue while post,delete or get but while updating or editing error will pop out.just get
rid of that property add migration and update database.

Comment: Just get rid of that property? Really?

Comment: Yess For me it worked... I was getting same error like cannot convert system.int32 to string. Just after removing that property don't forget to add migration and update database

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it worked, but you can't propose it as a general solution to just remove a property. It doesn't *answer* anything. Suppose we'd always do that. Your code has problems? Hey, just remove your code!

Comment: MaxLenght attribute in this case was placed on an integer, and that will fail in any circumstances.